# How to set a fixed width to Gridpane in Javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have got this gridPane in my code and i want to give it a fixed width of 800,i tried setting style like this

```
    grid.setStyle("width: 400px;");
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: a) Obvously it's not a good choice to use `400px` if you want the pane to be 800 pixel wide b) there is no `width` css property for `GridPane`; `-fx-min-width` `-fx-max-width` and/or `-fx-pref-width` could be used, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region c) there are circumstances where those values are ignored, e.g. if the node is the root of a scene with a size that does not satisfy the provided constraints...

Comment: Use _setMaxWidth()_ method or by using css _-fx-max-width_

Comment: Please accept the answer that works for you @OmarAlhadidy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

In this case `CSS` is not the best solution.

Try: `gridPane.setPrefWidth(800);`

If this doesn't work you can try:

```
gridPane.setMinWidth(800);
gridPane.setMaxWidth(800);
```

So your `GridPane` is definitely **800px width**